# Inefficient algorithm! Can you help me make this more efficient?

Tags: python, equation

In mathematics, a Diophantine equation is a polynomial equation, usually with two or more unknowns, such that only the integer solutions are sought or studied.

This is the equation:
`x**2 - 4 * y**2 = n`

(where the unknowns are `x` and `y`, and `n` is a given positive number.

My function iterates through every value between `0-n`. This is inefficient and can't always hack big `n` numbers. What is the best way to get the first unknown variable?

```py
def sol_equa(n):
    answers = []
    for x in range(1 , n+1):
        y = ((x ** 2 - n) / 4) ** (1 / 2)
        try:
            if y == y // 1:
                answers.append([x, int(y)])
        except TypeError:
            continue
    if len(answers) >= 1:
        answers = list(reversed(answers))
        return answers
    else:
        return []
```

`sol_equation(90005) --> "[[45003, 22501], [9003, 4499], [981, 467], [309, 37]]"`

Comment: Great background at [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html)

Comment: Note that `(x**2 - 4*y**2) = (x-2*y)*(x+2*y)`. So just factor `n`, and finding possible `x` and `y` from there should be easy...

Comment: hey! was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sympy.solvers.diophantine`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html). Take your equation as [image]

```
from sympy.solvers.diophantine import diophantine
from sympy.abc import x,y

n = 90005
solutions = diophantine(x**2 - 4*y**2 - n)
print(solutions)
#{(-981, 467), (-309, 37), (45003, 22501), (-45003, -22501), (309, -37), (-9003, -4499), (981, 467), (9003, -4499), (-9003, 4499), (45003, -22501), (309, 37), (-309, -37), (-45003, 22501), (9003, 4499), (981, -467), (-981, -467)}
```

If you want positive solutions only, you can use [set comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/set_comprehension.html):

```
positive_solutions = {sol for sol in solutions if sol[0] > 0 and sol[1] > 0}
print(positive_solutions)
#{(981, 467), (9003, 4499), (309, 37), (45003, 22501)}
```

**Execution time tests**

```
from timeit import timeit

sol_equa= '''
def sol_equa(n):
    answers = []
    for x in range(1 , n+1):
        y = ((x ** 2 - n) / 4) ** (1 / 2)
        try:
            if y == y // 1:
                answers.append([x, int(y)])
        except TypeError:
            continue
    if len(answers) >= 1:
        answers = list(reversed(answers))
        return answers
    else:
        return []
sol_equa(90005)
'''

sympy_solver = '''
def sympy_solver(n):
    solutions = diophantine(x**2 - 4*y**2 - n)
    return {sol for sol in solutions if sol[0] > 0 and sol[1] > 0}
sympy_solver(90005)
'''

setup = '''
from sympy.solvers.diophantine import diophantine
from sympy.abc import x,y
'''

print(timeit(sympy_solver,number=1000, setup = setup))
#13.50360608200208

print(timeit(sol_equa,number=1000))
#I don't know, it took too long :P
```